# fragment error at transaction add function's 2nd parameter

Tags: android, android-fragments

transaction add() Function and replace function error in android error in second argument of function

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:

                Chats c=new Chats();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content, Chats).commit();
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please try to explain your problem?  Also, please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass fragment object and not the class name as argument.

Change this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content, Chats).commit();
```

to

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content, c).commit();
```

Comment: at the time of clicking botton navigation app is close

Comment: @HarshPrajapati can you please add the crash logs??

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.dell.chattrack.Main2Activity@1cbdfd9 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                              at com.example.dell.chattrack.Home.onAttach(Home.java:83)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)

Comment: i try another way **"transaction.replace(R.id.content,new Chats(),null);
                   transaction.commit();"** this is also not working

Comment: look like you need to implement some interface in your activity. can you also add Home and Main2Activity files too